# Set up tracking scene makes my environment texture go black. Wha?

Tags: camera, tracking

[image]I set up my scene with an exr. But then I import a movie, track a ton of points, solve then hit the "set up tracking scene" button and my background turns black. The exr is still displaying in my world tab, but my scene just renders a black background. What could I be missing? Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: can you post an image of the nodes in the compositor?

Comment: I added a screenshot. It's just the basic set-up when you add an Environment texture. Before I hit the Setup Tracking Scene the image is visible in rendered mode. After, it all turns black.